Omnipay Integration Error for Paypal in a Laravel application
I'm integrating Paypal with my system, but I'm getting this error:
[2024-12-05 14:45:32] local.INFO: PayPal response: 
{"name":"AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE","message":"Authentication failed due to invalid 
authentication credentials or a missing Authorization header.","links":

With this integration code:
 public function generatePaypalPaymentByTransaction(Transaction $transaction) {
    try {
        $gateway = Omnipay::create('PayPal_Rest');
        $gateway->setClientId(env('PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID'));
        $gateway->setSecret(env('PAYPAL_SECRET'));
        $gateway->setTestMode(false);

        $urlHost = env('URL_HOST');


        $response = $gateway->purchase([
            'amount' => $transaction->amount,
            'currency' => env('PAYPAL_CURRENCY'),
            'returnUrl' => $returnUrl,
            'cancelUrl' => $cancel_url,
        ])->send();

        Log::info('PayPal response: ' . json_encode($response->getData()));

        if($response->isRedirect()) {
            $response->redirect();
        } else {
            return $response->getMessage();
        }
    } catch (Throwable $e){
        return $e->getMessage();
    }

But, the strange thing is that it works locally and not in production. But, in both environments the credentials are the same. So, I don't know what could be giving the error. The URL_HOST and CURRENCY are set in both cases.

"in both environments the credentials are the same" I would wager that they are not.

If the error is telling you that the authentication failed, then the chances are that it's not lying to you. So you need to revisit your assumption that the credentials are the same in both environments. Something will be wrong, or missing, or added to the wrong place, or not passing through, or whatever.  Probably an environment variable isn't set when you think it is. Do some debugging.

$gateway->setTestMode(false); in both environments?
